# Would University Professors be open to teaching short cohort based courses for massive financial upside?

Tags: workshop, consulting

As academics, professors and researchers possess a high level of subject matter expertise. However, many a times this knowledge is not accessible beyond small circles of people.

In such a scenario would academics be interested in teaching highly specific live online cohort based courses to external audiences and be monetarily rewarded for all the work that they put in?

Comment: There are companies that sell week long courses to other companies.  For example, let's say there is a demand for tool-X.   Then these companies will organize the logistics of hosting training courses at a location, and invite+pay experts (which may be academics or industry experts), etc.    They may also fly experts in from other other countries.   This can be quite lucrative.

Comment: Yeah something like this, but more accessible for learners. Ie- The learning happens online and price point is significantly less than in person events while still being able to interact with the instructor. This would make it easier for more professional learners to have access to top domain experts.

Comment: Define “massive”. Everyone has a price, so for the right definition of “massive” the answer is pretty obviously “yes”.

Comment: I would say something that helps them recreate their salary and make much more $ over time.

Comment: Is there grading involved?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Grading ?

Comment: @AnurajRawat Yes?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Not in the traditional nope.

Comment: What is the difference between what you are describing and at least more commercial MOOCs? Those have been around for at least a decade and there are enough predecessors such as recorded lecture series.

Answer (score 5):

That happens. Two examples of this happening are:

- Some summer schools get instructors from different universities and countries together. The instructors get some money from the summer school. This could range from a (partial) reimbursement of costs to a substantial fee, depending on who is organizing and who the intended audience is.
- Large organizations, like companies, government agencies, or international organizations have a budget for training their employees. Some hire academics to teach specific courses. This can be quite lucrative. There are agencies that specialize in bringing organization that want such courses and academics willing to teach those courses together, e.g.:  https://statisticalhorizons.com/

Comment: Thanks for expanding on this, this is precisely the kind of structure I am curious about. Additionally I was thinking if rather than just being trainers for these agencies the academics could create a brand under their own name.

Comment: Yes, a lot of these contacts start with informal networks and reputation rather than formal agencies.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, yes --- academics generally welcome opportunities to share their knowledge more widely than their formal classes, and they are also often under pressure to find external funding for their work.  There are companies that offer professional training courses in government, industry, etc., and sometimes they make use of academics for this training.  The financial upside for academics is not trivial, but it is certainly not "massive".  In my experience, some companies pay enough to attract academics, but some provide a lower rate-of-pay than an academic salary, so they have trouble attracting academic specialists.

Comment: Yes I have observed similar sentiments in the financial incentive being decent but nor massive. That's where my motivation lies, can we create infrastructure that enables Academics to instantly recreate or even surpass their salary through such arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard drug companies routinely pay physicians, including professors, substantial speaking fees.

Examples: https://www.denverpost.com/2013/03/25/colorado-doctors-take-big-speaking-fees-from-drug-companies-data-show/

Many professors will teach a short course for a small fee if the audience appeals to them.  Many would not do it for a large fee if they did not like the sponsor and audience.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question.

I want to address the issue of financial remuneration which, in your question, you suggest to be quite substantial.

This is pretty common in some academic disciplines. In others, it might be unusual.

An academic can accept fee-for-service consultancies, but they need to done within the regulations and policies of their university. Such consultancies, which may include the delivery of learning and teaching activities, is often covered by these policies. At the very least, some form of permission is usually sought from the academic's line management.

In specific cases, entering into a consultancy relationship with a specific company or industry may cause more harm than good institutionally. The classic example is receiving money from tobacco companies subsequently jeopardising access to grant funding opportunities. In these cases, there are clear institutional guidelines that the academic must obey.

The division of any "spoils" may also be under some rule. It is often very difficult, at least in my institution, for the payment to be received in whole by the academic. This is because the academic is already under salary. In most situations, nominal fees or perks may be passed off quite effectively as "reasonable expenses". For example, paying or reimbursing an academic's flights, accommodation and meals, or a small gift given at the end. In my institution, academics may also receive an honourarium, but this is capped and any excess is absorbed by the university.

Some academics have tried to get around these restrictions quite creatively. For example, one academic in my institution established a shell company and directed all payments to that company. Then, once the check cleared, she asked for personal leave and delivered the content in her own time. In this way, all the earnings were hidden from the university. Or so she thought. Once the university found out, she was fired for breach of contract, for misuse of the university name, and for misrepresentation of her status.

In the end, while a large financial inducement is quite flattering, there will probably be rules in place for this that an academic will consider and the university will certainly be involved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are, another example is open-source software developed by professors and their departments, there are multiple instances of courses and presentations as well as projects where the professors are the teachers or the one providing support in using the codes.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally teach courses in a workshop-like settings and hugely prefer that to more "traditional" ones spanning a whole semester or two. Sometimes it could be lucrative, too - even better!

Some of these offers I still decline if I feel the organizers do it to be able to put a checkmark somewhere, with clueless and unmotivated students and my name attached to it. Or when I am simply out of capacity.

So yes, absolutely, these offers are great as long as they are made sufficiently in advance and the students care about the material at least a tiny bit.

Comment: What if we could efficiently curate cohorts of highly motivated learners and not just those that attend such workshops as training requirements. Would academics like yourself run more of such workshops ?